# How to disable authentication in BetterAuthorizationSample?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authorization

I've implemented the BetterAuthorizationSample for the hope that the user would not be bombarded with the authentication dialog box for privilege operations. The implementation mostly works, however it does require the user to authenticate once. I want to disable authentication all together. Is this possible with the BetterAuthorizationSample?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This completely defeats the purpose of authorization. If there was any way for applications to perform privileged operations without the user's express consent, then malicious programs would be free to do whatever they wish.